# Need help in Merchello eCommerce Product Search functionality for front-end users

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco v.7.12.3 and Merchello v.2.7.0 and FastTrack v.2.7.0. package.

I am developing eCommerce website using Merchello. Now we have requirement that End-User can search product using Search Input text box Enter any Product Name or Keyword. Just like any eCommerce website have basic functionality for searching a product for buyer (End-User).

Is there any way in Merchello to get develop this functionality?

As I am new in Merchello and have limited knowledge, so I need help for Product Search functionality to develop for front-end users.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
public List<IProductContent> QuickSearch(string query)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query)) return new SearchResults();

    var searchProviderCollection = Examine.ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["MerchelloProductSearcher"];
    var searchResults = searchProviderCollection.Search(query, true)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Score);

    var merchelloHelper = new MerchelloHelper();
    var products = new List<IProductContent>();

    foreach (var searchResult in searchResults)
    {
        var node = merchelloHelper.TypedProductContent(new Guid(searchResult.Fields["productKey"]));
        products.Add(node);
    }

    return products;
}
```